# Custom comparison of HashSets

Tags: c#, union, hashset

I'm trying to create a custom comparer for my class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace i.changed.namespaces.DataStructures
{
public class Edge
{
    public Cords startPoint, endPont;
    public double length;

    //more code here that doesnt matter
}

public class EdgeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Edge>
{
    public bool Equals(Edge x, Edge y)
    {
        //Check whether the objects are the same object. 
        if (x.Equals(y)) return true;

        return x.startPoint.Equals(y.startPoint) && x.endPont.Equals(y.endPont) && (x.length - y.length < 0.0001);

    }

    public int GetHashCode(Edge obj)
    {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 23 + obj.length.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + obj.startPoint.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash *23 + obj.endPont.GetHashCode();

        return hash;
    }
}
```

}

I'm using this class in another object:

```
using i.changed.namespaces.DataStructures;
namespace i.changed.namespaces
public class MyClass
{
   HashSet<Edge> Edges, NewEdges;
   public MyClass()
   {
      NewEdges = new HashSet<Edge>();
      Edges = new HashSet<Edge>();
   }
```

and at some point I want to get a union of this hashsets:

```
newEdges.UnionWith(Edges);
```

but it looks like it's never using my EdgeComparer this way. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you use public HashSet(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer) to construct HashSet<T>?

Comment: @Lepijohnny added the question a bit, to show the construction.

Comment: Modify ctor call to pass EdgeComparer into. It should use then your custom comparer, e.g. new HashSet<Edge>(new EdgeComparer());

Comment: as @Lepijohnny mentioned when you create hashset pass the EqualityComparer

Comment: @Lepijohnny yeah, you was right. didn't find this way of construction myself. it helped me, thanks. Feel free to post it as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HashSet<T>` provides constructor where you can pass your custom implementation of the `IEqualityComparer<T>`. If you pass it, then it will be used otherwise `HashSet<T>` will be constructed using default `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

The solution for your problem is to modify your code slightly and pass your `EdgeComparer` into the `HasSet<Edge>` constructor

```
public MyClass()
{
    NewEdges = new HashSet<Edge>(new EdgeComparer());
    Edges = new HashSet<Edge>(new EdgeComparer());
}
```